# Rcpp function can't take std::set<int>?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm trying to create a C++ function through Rcpp that takes a `std:set<int>` as an argument. My goal is to append/insert it into a std::list. I may be missing something simple, but Rcpp seems to be choking when I try to use a `std::set<int>` argument.

Consider the following reproducible example:

```
    library(Rcpp)
    src1 = '
    #include <Rcpp.h>
    using namespace Rcpp;
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    List list_set() {
      std::list<std::set<int>> lz;
      std::set<int> tset = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
      lz.push_back(tset);
      return wrap(lz);
    }
    '
    sourceCpp(code = src1)
    list_set()

    src2 = '
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    List list_set2(std::set<int> tset) {
      std::list<std::set<int>> lz;
      lz.push_back(tset);
      return wrap(lz);
    }
    '
    sourceCpp(code = src2)
```

The output of the first function is the expected:

```
    > list_set()
    [[1]]
    [1] 10 20 30 40 50
```

The second function produces the following error when I try to compile:

```
    file6e04cf82f25.cpp:3:1: error: 'List' does not name a type 
    List list_set2(std::set<int> tset)
```

Note: replacing `List` with `std::list<std::set<int>>` also produces an error (thought it's something different).

Is there a simple fix I'm messing?

Comment: Remember that Rcpp is here to help interface between _R_ and C++. As such, we map existing R types to C++ (and back).  And R has no set.  There are packages on CRAN implementing sets though so maybe those will  help.

Comment: What @DirkEddelbuettel said. Also, a super easy fix is to pass an `Rcpp::IntegerVector tvec` and inside your function simply create a `std::set<int> tset(tvec.begin(), tvec.end());`. I haven't tested, but I'm sure something like that will work;

Comment: @Dirk I suspected something like that. And I want to thank you and the Rcpp team for all the work you put into Rcpp. It's an excellent help to many of us.  One piece of clarification. The function I imagine would actually be an internal function and would not need to be exported. Could I call the internal function as desired (with std::set<int> as an argument) from another exported function as long as the internal function is not exported?

Comment: @dr_jfrench, once you are in `C++`, you can do whatever legal `C++` the standard allows. It's the "getting to" `C++` that is the beauty of `Rcpp`.  I recommend looking at one of the 100s (maybe 1000s) of packages on CRAN that handle the step of getting information from `R`, doing something to it in `C++` and safely returning the result back to `R`. So, to answer your question, yes you can have `std::set` as a parameter to a function, just not the one that is exported.

Comment: Yes you can, but you can wrap an `[[Rcpp::export]]` around or expect other auto-generated parts to help because, as discussed, no wrappers for `std::set` exist.

Comment: @Joseph A mindboggling 1856 packages on CRAN alone use Rcpp.  Probably a few more 'out in the wild' -- but the CRAN ones are well curated and indeed an excellent source of "best practices".

Comment: @Joseph Thanks for the *super easy fix* and recommendations. That will be helpful for debugging purposes as I attempt to build my program.